# Different costs of call functions in Solidity in Remix

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I want to understand the Transaction Costs and Execution Costs of the following Code by the information given by Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract A {
    uint public b;
    function saveB(uint _b) public {
        b = _b;
    }
}
```

When I call the function to get the current value stored in b I get slightly different Transaction and Execution Costs each time although all my settings are still the same. I ran the Code in the Javascript VM.
The differences are not dramatically big, but I would like to understand the reason for it.
So for example I tried it a few hours ago with the following results:
Transaction Costs: 21.688
Execution Costs: 416

Then I tried it a just a few minutes ago:
Transaction Costs: 21.678
Execution Costs: 406

Could anybody explain me the reason for these differences?

Answer (score 1):

It is because space on the blockchain comes at a premium, so if you send the number 0x0100000000000000000000000000000000000000 for instance it will have the same cost as the number 0x01 this is because in both cases the same number of bytes have non-zero values in them, in this case 1. Then also sending 0 will give you a much lower value because it is clearing space, even if it was already 0 you still get the gas refund.